# Second spinner in "chain spinner android" doesn't show when first spinner is selected using mySQL database

Tags: android, mysql, android-spinner

I have a project to show chaining spinner Android using MySQL database. I have two tables: province and city. I also have two `Spinner`s for province and city. When I select a province, the city `Spinner` should show cities that is related to the selected province. Instead, it doesn't show anything. Can anyone help me?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private JSONArray data = null;

    private static final String TAG_SEMUA_KOMENTAR = "semua_subsektor";

    private static final String LINK = "http://10.0.2.2/asp/get_provinsi.php";

    private static final String JURU = "http://10.0.2.2/asp/get_kabupaten.php";
    ClassJSONParser json = new ClassJSONParser();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Permission StrictMode
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }

        // spinner1
        final Spinner spin = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

        final Spinner spin2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);

        try {
            JSONObject obj = json.ambilJsonDariUrl(LINK);

            data = obj.getJSONArray(TAG_SEMUA_KOMENTAR);
            final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
            HashMap<String, String> map;

            for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

                map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("id_provinsi", c.getString("id_provinsi"));
                map.put("nama_provinsi", c.getString("nama_provinsi"));
                MyArrList.add(map);
            }

            SimpleAdapter sAdap;
            sAdap = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, MyArrList,
                R.layout.coba,
                new String[] { "nama_provinsi" }, new int[] {
                R.id.ColName});

            spin.setAdapter(sAdap);
            spin.clearFocus();

            spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                        View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
                    try {
                        //spin.setSelection(position);
                        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id_provinsi", spin.getSelectedItem().toString()));

                        JSONObject obj1 = json.membuatHttpRequest(JURU, "GET", params);

                        data = obj1.getJSONArray(TAG_SEMUA_KOMENTAR);
                        final ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> MyArrList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
                        HashMap<String, String> map; 

                        for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

                            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                            map.put("id_kabupaten", c.getString("id_kabupaten"));
                            map.put("nama_kabupaten", c.getString("nama_kabupaten"));
                            map.put("id_provinsi", c.getString("id_provinsi"));
                            MyArrList.add(map);
                        }

                        SimpleAdapter sAdap1;
                        sAdap1 = new SimpleAdapter(MainActivity.this, MyArrList,
                            R.layout.coba,
                            new String[] { "nama_kabupaten" }, new int[] {
                            R.id.ColName});
                        spin2.setAdapter(sAdap1);

                        sAdap1.notifyDataSetChanged();

                        spin2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0,
                                    View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {

                            }

                            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                    "Your Selected : Nothing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Your Selected : Nothing", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show();
                }
            });
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please explain what is not working. Does the app crash? Nothing happened?

Comment: Nothing happen, the second spinner not show anything

Comment: Could you debug your code and make sure that you get some data for `MyArrList` and `sAdap`?

Comment: Yes, MyArrlist for first spinner works, but the second's not